# how to get the generated Ember.Component HTML

Tags: ember.js, components, gridster

I am using Emberjs and Gridsterjs to create some kind of editor. I found out that you need to make a component to include a jQuery plugin in Emberjs. Inside that component i have a number of components that will become the widgets for the Gridster.

this is how i've setup my templates:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  {{#create-gridster}}
    {{create-widget}}
  {{/create-gridster}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/create-gridster">
  <button class="btn" {{action 'newWidget'}}>add widget.</button>
  <section class="gridster-wrapper">
    <div class="gridster">
      <ul id="gridster-list">
        {{yield}}
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
</script>
```

Now i've created a button that allows the user to add a widget to the Gridster, but i can't seen to find a way to give the requested HTML string for the widget from the component.

I've tried this:

```
this.get('gridster').add_widget(Ember.Handlebars.compile('{{create-widget}}'));
```

and this:

```
this.get('gridster').add_widget(App.CreateWidgetComponent.create().createElement());
```

but that doesn't seen to work.

**QUESTION**
My question is how do i create the html string that gridster expects and keep the ember functionality for editting the content.

Comment: What makes you think you need to use a component to include a jQuery plugin in Ember? Sure, it's often a good way to replicate plugin code snippets in a DRY way but you can include a jQuery plugin in any number of different ways. For example, in this situation you might be better off using a Em.CollectionView

Comment: I see why Em.CollectionView is the better option. But that won't fix my problem.

Comment: My point was your statement "you need to make a component to include a jQuery plugin" is incorrect. In this case, if you use a `Em.CollectionView` for the grid with an `itemViewClass` for each box in the grid, you specify the template for each item and that template will be the html string you need for the widget. If each item has dynamic class or attribute bindings (e.g. styling for width, position, or adding a class) you can use bindings in the `itemViewClass` to do that too. The create-widget button will simply add a javascript object to the array of gridster content, not 'create' html.

Answer (score 0):

In myprettycms (myprettycms.codeplex.com) I use gridster to create layout, then to edit the content of the gridster li, I superpose a tiny mce on the slot and I transfert the content of the slot to tinyMCE instance.

When it's finish, I transfert TinyMCEContent in the slot.

See : http://myprettycms.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#MyPrettyCMSCommunityManager/Portals/MVC4Portal/Scripts/Views/DynaContentAdmin.js